# accessing dynamically added image to a listbox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

unable to access the selected image in the listbox

.xaml code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" Margin="10,282,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight" ItemWidth="120" ItemHeight="120"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="b" Click="b_Click_1" Width="120" Height="120" >
                            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            Margin="-10,-10,-10,-10" 
                            x:Name="image1" 
                            Stretch="Fill" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding}"
                        />
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

.cs code:

```
   private void b_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          try
        {
            MessageBoxResult a = MessageBox.Show("Are you want to upload", "Photo Upload", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            if (a == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
 System.Drawing.Image b1 = (sender as Button).DataContext as System.Drawing.Image;
           }
        }
    }
```

In the above code of .cs file 'b1' is showing 'null' value even after i click on the image.

Comment: There is no `Bitmap` in the `DataContext` of the Button. There is an `Image` control in the `Content` of the button, and from your previous question we know there is a file path string in the `DataContext`. I'd strongly suggest to read up on this topic (and perhaps WPF in general) before starting to code.

Comment: `System.Drawing.Image` is also wrong. It's a [`System.Windows.Controls.Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx). Start reading the [Imaging Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx) article on MSDN. Really!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the image?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Image` control is in the `Button.Content` property, not the `Button.DataContext` property. Also, the `Image` control is not a `Bitmap`. Try this:

```
Image image = ((Button)sender).Content as Image;
```

Or in case you only want to access the image file path:

```
var imageFile = ((Button)sender).DataContext as string;
```

Comment: @Clemens is right... you need to go and do some WPF reading. Although I don't know why he didn't just add his own answer instead of changing mine. Clemens, your addition changes the meaning of my answer and doesn't even make sense unless you read his other post which is not even linked to from here. Bad edit. :(

Comment: Your answer is more or less just a copy of what has previously been written as comment to the question. But it is incomplete without this addition, as it isn't actually clear what OP is going to do with the image in the button. Does he or she want to access the bitmap or the image file? At least the message box title mentions an upload, so my guess is that accessing the file and uploading it somewhere isn't a completely unrealistic purpose.

Comment: No, you're wrong. This question is named `selecting dynamically added image to a listbox in wpf`. It mentions nothing about file paths or `DataContext`s. As it is, I've left your edit in place, so please just let this go now.